# nhibernate random data from database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
    IList<Companies> companies = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Companies))   
.AddOrder(new RandomOrder())                                
                                    .SetMaxResults(3)
                                    .List<Companies>();


public class RandomOrder : Order
        {
            public RandomOrder() : base("", true) { }
            public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
            {
                return new NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString("newid()");
            }
        }
```

how can i make random data from DB. 3 of them. Code i paste not working very well.

Comment: The question being asked is very unclear. Please can you rephrase it?

Comment: I believe @senzacionale is asking for a method to extract a random sample of 3 records from a database using nhibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work... though it'll require 2 db calls:

```
public IEnumerable<Company> GetRandomCompanies(int maxSelections)
{
    try
    {
        IList<int> companyIds = _session.CreateCriteria<Company>() // get all available company ids
            .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.Property<Company>(c => c.Id)).List<int>();

        return _session.CreateCriteria<Company>()
            .Add(Restrictions.In(LambdaProjection.Property<Company>(c => c.Id), GetRandomCompanyIds(companyIds.ToList(), maxSelections))) // get 3 random Ids
            .List<Company>();
    }
    catch (Exception xpt)
    {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(xpt);
    }

    return new List<Company>();
}

private List<int> GetRandomCompanyIds(List<int> companyIds, int maxSelections)
{
    List<int> randomIds = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxSelections; i++)
    {
        // this will get you the same result all day, new next day
        // it might not be what you need, so you could just use a new seed.
        Random rng = new Random(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear);
        randomIds.Add(companyIds[rng.Next(companyIds.Count)]);
    }

    return randomIds;
}
```

**edit:** also, I haven't tested this at all so who knows what it'll do! It should be at least on the right track. Maybe there's a way that doesn't require 2 db calls

Answer (score 0):

In Nhibernate you can simply select random rows like so using SQL

```
var query = "SELECT top 3 * from [Companies] ORDER BY NEWID()";
ISQLQuery qry = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).AddEntity(typeof(Companies));
Companies randomCompanies = qry.List<Companies>();
```

Comment: This is not a good idea.  For a start he hasn't specified what DB he is using, and this will only work with MSSQL.  You'd have to use a different DB specific feature if you wanted to get it to work in say MySQL.  More importantly this will lead to awful query performance.  See [this post](http://www.endyourif.com/why-you-should-avoid-order-by-rand-or-newid/) for info.